# "Delimiter" is not valid at this position, expecting CREATE

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I was getting an error of "Delimiter" is not valid at this position, expecting CREATE" as I was writing a stored procedure and couldn't figure out the cause. I think it might be an issue with MySQL workbench possibly, because the following code gives the same error but was copied straight off of [this website](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/variables-in-stored-procedures.aspx/).

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTotalOrder()
BEGIN
    DECLARE totalOrder INT DEFAULT 0;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO totalOrder
    FROM orders;
    
    SELECT totalOrder;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Edit:** My real stored procedure is:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSimilar(inputdate char(10))
BEGIN
    Declare id(tinyint) DEFAULT 0;
    Set id := (select t.IdTimelineinfo
        From timelineinfo t
        WHERE t.Date = inputdate);
    SELECT t.Date From timelineinfo t where t.date = inputdate;
    SELECT o.Name, o.Race, o.Sex, o.IdOfficer
        FROM timelineinfo
        JOIN timelineinfo_officer ON timelineinfo.IdTimelineinfo = timelineinfo_officer.IdTimelineinfo      
        JOIN officers o ON timelineinfo_officer.IdOfficer = o.IdOfficer
        WHERE timelineinfo.IdTimelineinfo = id
        UNION
    SELECT s.IdSubject, s.Name, s.Race, s.Sex
        FROM timelineinfo
        JOIN timelineinfo_subject ON timelineinfo.IdTimelineinfo = timelineinfo_subject.IdTimelineinfo      
        JOIN subjects s ON timelineinfo_subject.IdSubject = s.IdSubject
        WHERE timelineinfo.IdTimelineinfo = id;
        UNION
    Select * 
        From media m
        Where (m.IdTimelineinfo = id);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: In your particular case you may convert thу procedure to single-statement form `CREATE PROCEDURE GetTotalOrder() SELECT COUNT(*) totalOrder FROM orders;` and avoid DELIMITER usage at all.

Comment: That might work for that issue but it doesn't solve the actual problem, I edited my question to show that that wouldn't work for my actual stored procedure because I have more than one statement

Comment: I think it would be logical to study the documentation for the client tool which you use, it must contain the information about procedures creation - for example, it is possible that you must use some special window type or some definite delimiter or set some option like "send as raw SQL"... or maybe you may find such info using search by this site or DBA.STACKEXCHANGE.COM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out where you edit the procedure SQL code. There's a dedicated routine object editor (just like there are for tables, triggers, views etc.), which only accept SQL code for their associated object type. Hence they don't need a delimiter and even signal an error if you use one.

On the other hand you can always directly edit SQL code in the SQL IDE code editors, where no such special handling is implemented. In this case you need the delimiter.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I was attempting to add a new stored procedure using MySQL Workbench and clicking on "Create Stored Procedure"

Comment: This command opens a dedicated stored routine object editor. You see the same when you right click on a stored routine (procedure/function) in the schema tree and select Edit... from the context menu.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining, I'm rather new to this sort of thing